# Migrate history data from one org to another

Tags: data-loader, migration, data-migration

We have a migration project from one salesforce org to a new salesforce org. We have migrated all the configuration and data. Now the client wants to know whether the history data (accountHistory, CaseHistory, contactHistory etc) can be migrated. I tried the dataloader and was able to export the history data, as shown in figure 1, but when I tried the import (Insert) all the history related objects disappeared. Any solution to that? and if not, any particular reason why the history cant be moved?

[image: export]
[image: import]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes, history cannot be created since AccountHistory, CaseHistory and ContactHistory doest't support create() operation. 
See the following docs for more information.
[Account History SOAP API](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_accounthistory.htm)
[Contact History SOAP API](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contacthistory.htm)
[Case History SOAP API](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_casehistory.htm)

Your best bet will to create a custom object and store history information in it.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that it is possible to migrate data into the History tables. They do not have the "createable" or "updateable" attributes that would allow you to populate them.

The reason is that they are audit tables. If you could edit your audit trail, it would not be entirely useful as an audit trail.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't migrate history object.
It can be downloaded but insert on this type of object is impossible.

> "Note that it is not possible to insert directly into the Opportunity
>   History or Case History tables. These tables mainly carry the field
>   audit history information of Opportunity or Case records. If such data
>   does need to be migrated over, you should migrate this data into a
>   Read Only Custom Object. "

Answer (score 0):

you  can not insert history data from data loader .
History aromatically create when any changes made by user on record .

Answer (score 0):

Create operation is not possible on AccountHistory that is why these  objects were disabled on Dataloader Import .

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to migrate the History (AccountHistory, CaseHistory, ContactHistory etc) from one org to another.  However, what you might consider is importing the old history data into a Custom object.